# Write double integral from D

Tags: surface-integrals

$D$ - sector in picture
[image]

*I solve it and want know if it's right solution.*

### My solution

$D = \{-y \leq x \leq y, -1 \leq y \leq 1 \}$, so $\iint\limits_{D}f(x, y) = 
\int\limits_{-1}^{1}dy \int\limits_{-y}^{y}f(x, y)dx$

Comment: The segment berween $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ in the picture should be horizontal if $D=\{−y≤x≤y,−1≤y≤1\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your upper bound of y is '1' but as you can see the area you want to integrate at x=0 has an upper bound somewhere between 1 and 2. 
You only integrate the rectangle given by the points (0.0) (-1,1) (1,1)
Do you know polar coordinates ? By that your figure can easily be descirbed as a quater of a circle with radius 1 arround (0,0)

Comment: Maybe I must use two part of this figure like $D = D_1 + D_2$ ?

Comment: Yes it can be done in that way too  :)